# Searching particular data from SQL in VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, loops

I want to search a particular data from SQL and then match it to cells in Excel.

A cell in Excel is PART NUMBER, I want to show values from the Link and Critical columns from SQL that have PART NUMBER. Also, if the PART NUMBER ON the Excel is not matched to PART NUMBER in SQL, then leave it NULL.

Here is the Excel:

[image]

And this is my SQL

[image]

and this is my Current failed code

```
Sub Run_Report()
Dim SQL As String
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim DatabaseName As String
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lcol As Long
Dim var As Variant
Dim partnum As Variant
Dim part As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim result As Long
var = "%" & Range("D3").Value & "%"

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
partnum = Cells(i, 1).Value

Server_Name = "FSNGPZ\SQLEXPRESS"
DatabaseName = "QualityEngineeringDB"
part = "Select SQTLogbook.PART# from QualityEngineeringDB.dbo.SQTLogbook"
Call Connect_TTo_SQLServer(Server_Name, DatabaseName, SQL)
Application.CalculateFullRebuild

For i = 9 To lrow
    If Cells(i, 1) = part Then
Server_Name = "FSNGPZ\SQLEXPRESS"
DatabaseName = "QualityEngineeringDB"
SQL = "Select SQTLogbook.Link, SQTLogbook.Critical From QualityEngineeringDB.dbo.SQTLogbook where QualityEngineeringDB.dbo.SQTLogbook.PART# = '" & partnum & "';"
Call Connect_TTo_SQLServer(Server_Name, DatabaseName, SQL)
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
Set result = sqlProcess(SQL)
Columns(i, 4).Value = result(0)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it say when it fails?

Comment: Your code contains calls to other methods you have not included in your post (and which seem to be responsible for the actual connection and queries), and you haven't explained what goes wrong when you run your code, so it's unclear how we could help fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Make the connection to the server once and use a parametized query.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Run_Report()

    Const SERVER_NAME = "FSNGPZ\SQLEXPRESS"
    Const DB_NAME = "QualityEngineeringDB"

    Const SQL = " SELECT Link, Critical" & _
                " FROM SQTLogbook" & _
                " WHERE PART# = ?"

    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, i As Long, icount As Long
    
    Set conn = ConnectToServer(SERVER_NAME, DB_NAME)
    
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
    End With
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 9 To lastrow
        cmd.Parameters(0).Value = Trim(ws.Cells(i, "A")) ' part num
        Set rs = cmd.Execute()
        If rs.EOF Then
            ws.Cells(i, "D") = "NULL"
            ws.Cells(i, "E") = "NULL"
        Else
            ws.Cells(i, "D") = rs(0)
            ws.Cells(i, "E") = rs(1)
            icount = icount + 1
        End If
    Next i
    conn.Close
    MsgBox icount & " rows matched", vbInformation
   
End Sub

Function ConnectToServer(SERVER As String, DB As String) As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB" & _
              ";Server=" & SERVER & _
              ";Database=" & DB & _
              ";Trusted_Connection=yes;"

    Set ConnectToServer = New ADODB.Connection
    ConnectToServer.Open strConn   
End Function
```